# 2Darray to 1darray with for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I know this is a very basic question, but I'm just new to programming and I think I'am struggling with a very simple issue... but here we go :p

In my app I have an array of arrays like this storing data retrieved from a mysql database.

```
data_array[][]

0001 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
0002 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
...
... and so on.
```

Now in my app, I need to retrieve for each of the rows the first of the colums, ending with something like :

```
array { 0001, 0002}
```

I know doing ' for iterations ' I can retrieve all the data:

```
public String[] itarray{
int cols = 5;
String[] xFINAL;
for (int i=0 ; i < data_array; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < cols; j++){
        xFINAL = data_array[i];
        System.out.println("1" + data_array[i][0]);

    }

System.out.println(" ");
} return xFINAL;}
```

But how can I get the first column for each of the rows? I tried with something like:

```
int j=0;
for (int i = 0; i < data_array ; i++){
 xFINAL[j] = data_array [i][0];
j++;
}
```

But it's giving me a null pointer. How could I do this please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a little tip - You don't need that "j" there (for the last code block you have there). Just use the i (it increments by 1 as well).

Comment: You get a null pointer exception because `xFinal` is not initialized. Use `xFinal = new String[data_array.length]` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] xFINAL = new String[data_array.length];   

int k =0;
for (int i=0 ; i < data_array; i++) {
    array[k++] = data_array[i][0];


}
```

Comment: had to do a little change here: for (int i=0 ; i < data_array.length; i++) . But its working now. Thanks a lot all of you guys!